# android to draw vertical line using style tag inside CDATA in string file

Tags: android

To draw vertical line to left of text.

My string file looks like this
    < string name="first2">
     < ![CDATA[
      < div style="border-left:3px solid #8080ff;height:15px;float:left"/>< font color="#8080ff"> public< /font>
    ]]>
    < /string>

and my java file uses this string like this
    Spanned sp=Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.first2));
    TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    tv2.setText(sp);

But I dint get that vertical line

Comment: tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.first2))); just try this one

Comment: Actually u want to draw a line right...?

Comment: There is a very limited set of HTML tags supported by TextView. You'll have better luck with a WebView and using `Html.fromHtml(String)` though depending on use case, it's likely to make more sense to styling natively.

Answer (score 0):

Salaam, you can just use these tags in cdata:

b, strong   :Bold
i, em, cite, dfn    :Italics
u   :Underline
sub     :Subtext
sup     :Supertext
big     :Big
small   :Small
tt  :Monospace
h1 … h6     :Headlines
img     :Image
font    :Font face and color
blockquote  :For longer quotes
a   :Link
div, p :    Paragraph
br  :Linefeed

use a webView instead of TextView!